# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded in a post request in webclient?

Tags: c#, webclient

I know I can send json but I couldn't find how to send x-www-form-urlencoded. I don't know what to try as I couldn't find anything.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();


string data = "channel_id=+12039273888&channel_type=phone&channel_verification=514950";

wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string result = wc.UploadString("http://3.86.171.88/api/login", data);

System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `UploadString()` method on `WebClient` class like

```
string data = "name=john&age=20&city=Uganda";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string result = client.UploadString(url of api resource, data);
}
```

Comment: i try to add that in my code and i get a 402 error - unprocessable indetitity.

Answer (score 8):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
);

content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(https://some url...), content);
```

hope this helps.. since HttpClient is latest also lean towards restapi better..